# How to parse JSON object from a website into an arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

How can I parse a JSON object from a weblink into Android and store the different values into ArrayLists?

The JSON object of users looks like the below. It comes from a website.

```
{"Users":[{"name":"Kane","lon":"4.371645","lat":"31.396911"},
          {"name":"Sam","lon":"4.129737","lat":"31.194824"},
          {"name":"Ryan","lon":"4.023134","lat":"31.298222"},
          {"name":"Jerry","lon":"4.262276","lat":"31.295054"}]}
```

I want to parse in into Android and store the different values like name, lon and lat into an array list.

My ultimate goal is to use the JSON object to place markers on a map activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library to parse `JSON` to java class. It is very simple to use.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(jsonLine, Users.class);
```

Generated model example:

```
   public class Users {

       @SerializedName("Users")
       @Expose
       public List<User> Users = new ArrayList<User>();
    }


    public class User {

       @SerializedName("name")
       @Expose
       public String name;

       @SerializedName("lon")
       @Expose
       public double lon;

       @SerializedName("lat")
       @Expose
       public double lat;

   }
```

Comment: I think it is wrong. Because the question says that to store different values into ArrayList. However your answer returns an Object.  If you want to aim Collections via Gson, look at https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#collections-examples

Comment: @dieter_h how to I get the actual data from the website using your answer?

Comment: jsonLine is `string` with `JSON`. If you want to get `JSON` from server use  `Volley` lib.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Model class from your data model like:

```
public class DataTemplate{

public final List<User> Users;

public DataTemplate(List<User> Users){
    this.Users = Users;
}

public static class User{
    public final String name;
    public final double lon;
    public final double lat;

    public User(String name, double lon, double lat){
        //initialize elements
    }
} }
```

After that take a look at [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library. Using that you can simply import the data as:

```
DataTemplate getTemplate(String path){
    try {
        return new Gson().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(dataFromURLRequest),  DataTemplate.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

After this, just directly retrieve the list from DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(HttpUtil.BASIC_URL
                + HttpUtil.SUBSCRIPTION_URL);
        try{
            if (cookie != null) {
               // httpClient.setCookieStore(LoginJsonUtil.cookie);
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid",
                        uid));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subscriptionslist[pageindex]",
                        subscriptionslist_pageindex));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subscriptionslist[recordlimit]",
                        subscriptionslist_recordlimit));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
```

Comment: if you get a url like url+/?r=m/calendar/contact_list&uid=3&&subscriptionslist[pageindex]=10&subscriptionslist[recordlimit]=10 this will be ok

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native JSONObject and JSONArray present on the Android SDK here : https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

There is a method named `JSONObject(String json)` that allow you to do something like this (not tested) :

```
//creating your json object from your strong
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourString);
JSONArray users = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");//this two lines throws a JSONException so put try{}catch{} block
for(JSON user in users)
{
        JSONObject currentUser = users.get(i);
        //insert yout user inside your ArrayList here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class that can store the results and appropiate constructor you can use code like below, using this [json.org](http://www.json.org/) library for [Java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java),

```
import org.json.*;

ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();

JSONObject o = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("Users");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
   JSONObject user = arr.getJSONObject(i);

   users.add(new Users(user.getString("name"),user.getDouble("lat"),user.getDouble("lon")));  

   }

}
```